# Does the store object in vuex fall through to leaf components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Following the docs:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components

and the video tutorial:

https://scrimba.com/scrim/ckMZp4HN?pl=pnyzgAP

it's not clear (to me) whether store is visible in nested/child components present in the component that includes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs you've linked (emphasis mine):

> You can commit mutations in components with `this.$store.commit('xxx')`, or use the `mapMutations` helper which maps component methods to `store.commit` calls (requires ***root `store` injection***)

If you've set up Vuex so that you have "root `store` injection", then this means that `store` is *globally accessible* within your Vue instance.
That is– store, through the `$store` instance property, is an accessible property (is visible) in every nested/ child component present in the entire Vue instance component tree.

This is arguably what makes Vuex so powerful; Vuex allows all components to have state access, but still maintains detailed tracking for every state interaction that occurs.

Comment: Trying it now on nested components